# Galera cluster JDBC URL for automatic failover

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, galera

I've used `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` with the following URL for load balancing and it worked:

```
jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://node1,node2,node3/mydb
```

Using the above URL, queries are randomly distributed among the three nodes. Now I need to have a **failover** setup in which all queries are sent to only and only one node and once that node is gone, the next available node should be selected for all queries thereafter.

My cluster is a multimaster. This means that the new node after a failover still gets both read and write queries. The reason why I do not want load balancing is [to reduce deadlock problems](http://www.severalnines.com/blog/avoiding-deadlocks-galera-set-haproxy-single-node-writes-and-multi-node-reads).

What JDBC URL do you think I should use?

**P.S.**

I've used `jdbc:mysql://node1,node2,node3/mydb` with `com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver` but it makes the selected node after a failover read-only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a failover connection with failoverReadOnly=false.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee-concepts-load-balancing-failover.html

Comment: Thanks. This parameter is documented as: "When failing over in autoReconnect mode, should the connection be set to 'read-only'?" But I do not want to use autoReconnect mode as it is a source of some other problems.

Comment: The FailoverConnectProxy actually does respect this. I just confirmed in the code.